# Mount Bitlocker TPM partition

Tags: windows, mount, encryption, tpm

My plan is to encrypt my Windows system with Bitlocker (and TPM). But I wonder if I'm able to mount the system with Linux. I know Linux is able to mount Bitlocker partitions but is it also able to mount partitions encrypted with the use of a TPM?

Comment: Did you ever found the solution? sorry for adding an answer but I can't comment.

Comment: Unfortunately no. My workaround was to use the recovery-key to mount it in Linux. Just as a note: if you plan to do so, your Linux should be encrypted too, because otherwise the key can be read by anyone with access to the disk; therefore rendering the encryption useless.